# Append duplicate items at the end of list whithout changing the order

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting

I am new to python and was trying to Append duplicate items at the end of list whithout changing the order

```
testlist = [1, 2, 32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56]

def duplicate(alist):
    p = len(alist)
    duplicate = False
    for i in range(0, p):
        for j in range (i + 1, p):
            if alist[i] == alist[j]:
                b = alist.index(alist[j])
                a = alist.pop(b)
                alist.append(a)
                p -= 1
                duplicate = True

    print alist

if duplicate == False:
    print "No duplicate item found"

duplicate(testlist)
```

OUTPUT : `[32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56, 1, 2]`

DESIRED OUTPUT : `[1, 2, 32, 8, 17, 5, 42, 13, 56, 1, 2]`

Any help what wrong I am doing here

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code? We can't tell if you have an issue from incorrect indentation or not :)

Comment: What do you think `alist.pop(b)` does?

Comment: Your code should at least be free of syntax errors (unless it's the syntax you need help with). This code is not currently grammatical Python

Comment: @KarlKnechtel was trying to get the 2nd duplicate element here.
    

    if alist[i]==alist[j]:
                a=alist.pop(j)
                alist.append(a)
                p-=1

    will work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in this case the creation of a new list is more efficient and clear in comparison with the permutations in the original list:

```
testlist = [1, 2, 32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56]

def duplicate(alist):

    filtered, duplicates = [], []
    for element in alist:
        if element in filtered:
            duplicates.append(element)
            continue
        filtered.append(element)

    if not duplicates:
        print "No duplicate item found"
        return alist
    return filtered + duplicates

new_list = duplicate(testlist)
print new_list
```

Comment: I made something similar, just used a set for already seen elements. I think it's the best answer.

Comment: `set` isn't save order, so it's not needed here

Comment: Yes it wasn't clear, I meant a set to know which elements are already seen but the duplicate elements are indeed put in a list. Doesn't make much a difference anyway, that's why I didn't made an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Collections module to get `OrderedDict` for maintaining the order of elements.

The technique we use here is to create a dictionary to store the number of occurrences of each element in the array and use the `dict` to lookup the number of occurrences for later use.

In the `for` loop we look up if there is already element present in the `dict` using the `get` method. If `true` then we increase the counter else initialize the counter to be zero.

```
import collections
lst = [1, 2, 32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56]

# Create a dictionary storing the the number of occurences
occurences_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in lst:
    occurences_dict[i] = occurences_dict.get(i, 0) + 1

final = occurences_dict.keys() + [k for k, v in occurences_dict.items() if v>1]

print final
>>> [1, 2, 32, 8, 17, 5, 42, 13, 56, 1, 2]
```

Comment: your solution involves the creation and filling of the dictionary, the creation and concatenation of the lists ... not too expensive for the permutations of the list?

Comment: But that would never get to `O(n^2)`, it would be still be `O(n)` if you see clearly.

Comment: Ok, it'll be `O(n)` but you iterate list twice. Plus you use comparison in the second loop.

Comment: BTW did a small time test and it yielded: `0.0149569511414 second` and
`0.100003004074 seconds` for my and your approach respectively on a `10000` random elements list. Give a try: `lst = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way.  I also made some changes to make the code a bit more Pythonic.

```
test_list = [1, 2, 32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56]

def duplicate(a_list):
    list_length = len(a_list)
    duplicate = False
    checked = []
    for i in range(list_length):
        if a_list.count(a_list[i]) > 1:
            if a_list[i] not in checked:
                duplicate = True
                a_list.append(a_list[i])
                checked.append(a_list[i])
    if duplicate == False:
        print("No duplicate item found")
        return None
    return a_list

print(duplicate(test_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking values, compare on index.

Please check this code:

```
testlist = [1, 2, 32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56,32]

print("Original list - ",testlist)
tmp_list = []
exclude =[]
for i in range(len(testlist)):
    if i == testlist.index(testlist[i]):

        tmp_list.append(testlist[i])
    else:
        exclude.append(testlist[i])
tmp_list.extend(exclude)
testlist = tmp_list

print("Updated list - ",testlist)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Original list -  [1, 2, 32, 8, 1, 17, 5, 2, 42, 13, 56, 32]
Updated list -  [1, 2, 32, 8, 17, 5, 42, 13, 56, 1, 2, 32]

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a algo which extends the duplicates in such a way that if duplicate contains duplicate we are extends them to end also

eg - input -  [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,2,5]
output - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2] - (Solution 2)

others ouput - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3] where 2 repeats (Solution 1)

Solution 1 -

```
def remove_extend(l):
    stack = []
    duplicates = []

    for i in l:
        if i not in stack:
            stack.append(i)
        elif i in stack:
            duplicates.append(i)
    
    stack.extend(duplicates)

    return stack

l =  [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5]
ans = remove_extend(l)
print(l)
print(ans)
```

Solution 2

```
def check_dict(d):
    if d == {}:
        return False
    # stack = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        
        if v == 0:
            del d[k]
        
        return True

def add_to_stack(stack, d):
    for k,v in d.items():
           
            if v>=1:
                stack.append(k)
                d[k] -= 1
    return [stack,d]      


def duplicates_extend2(ls):
    d = {}
    stack = []
    for i in ls:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1


    print(d)
    if_dict = check_dict(d)
    while if_dict:
        ans  = add_to_stack(stack, d)
        stack = ans[0]
        d = ans[1]
        if_dict = check_dict(d)
        

    return stack


ls = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,2,5]
ans = duplicates_extend2(ls)
print(ans)
```